# istio preserve client-ip from pod on onpremise

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, istio, proxy-protocol

#### I need to know client ip from pod where it is running on istio on onpremise.

```
Is there something wrong from my configurations ?   
The ingressgateway is not loadbalancer, nodeport service.   

When I configure the TPROXY in application deployemnt, it always show ip of ingressgateway pod.   
When I don't configure the TROXY in application deployemtn, it always show 127.0.0.6.   

I don't konw why a POD don't get client-ip from proxy-protocol.   
Could you know how to configure ?   
I configured as follow for proxy protocol.
```

Traffic flow : Haproxy -> Ingressgateway(NodePort) -> Gateway -> Service -> POD

1. Haproxy

- Comment: I configure the haproxy for proxy protocol
- LoadBalancer: L4
- Proxy protocol Port: 7559

  1.1 haproxy.cfg

```
listen nginx-in-istio
    bind        *:7559
    mode        tcp
    option      tcplog
    server  backend01   172.16.6.202:30740 check send-proxy-v2
```

2. Ingressgateway

- Comment : I configure ingressgateway for only proxy protocol
- Service: NodePort
- Ingressgateway Pod Label: ingressgateway-cwmp
- Envoy Filter :

  2.1 Envoyr Filter for proxyprotocol

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: proxy-protocol-cwmp
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway-cwmp
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: LISTENER
    match:
       listener:
          name: "0.0.0.0_7559"
          portNumber: 7559
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        listener_filters:
        - name: envoy.listener.proxy_protocol
        - name: envoy.listener.tls_inspector
```

2.2 Envoyr Filter for X-fowarded-for

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: ingressgateway-settings-x-forwarede-for-cwmp
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway-cwmp
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
          skip_xff_append: false
          use_remote_address: true
          xff_num_trusted_hops: 2
```

2.3 Ingress gateway POD YAML for proxy protocol

```
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        proxy.istio.io/config: '{"gatewayTopology" : { "numTrustedProxies": 2 } }'
```

3.application deployment YAML

```
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:                 
        app: nginx
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/interceptionMode: TPROXY
```

Comment: In HAProxy you should mention "accept-proxy" to preserve the client IP.  Following HAProxy documentation has sample for frontend and backend configuration. 
 https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/load-balancing/client-ip-preservation/enable-proxy-protocol/.